# Assign css class in jQuery based on razor C# list count

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having a css menu for notifications. It's all in a div. Inside this div I have a link which, when hovered, shows the notifications in a menu like fashion.

I want to change the background color of the div if there are notifications and remove the background color if the link has been hovered. I want to use the count property of a  C# razor variable named "templates" which stores the templates of the notifications to be showed in the menu.

I want to do something like this in javascript/jquery

```
$(document).ready(function())
{
  if(@templates.Count > 0)
  {
    $('#notificationsMenuItem').addClass('notifNotSeen');
  }
}

 function changeBackground() {
    var menu = $('#notificationsMenuItem');

    if(menu.hasClass('notifNotSeen'))
        menu.removeClass('notifNotSeen');
}
```

Here is the div that contains the menu structure:

```
<div id="notificationsMenuItem" class="divList">
   <a href="#" style="font-weight: normal; padding: 0;"   onmousedown="changeBackground()">Notifications</a>
........


 </div>
```

Is this possible? What other ways to do this are there?

Comment: Should be possible pretty much the way you wrote it up there. It will output "dynamic" javascript, which of course if looked at in the file will look a bit silly, as there it appears as hard-coded values, e.g. `if (5 > 0) { ... }` - but it will work nevertheless.

Comment: @UweB, my problem is this doesn't work as it is, I can't assign the value of a C# server side variable to a jQuery javascript function.

Comment: Okay - what exactly is @templates? Because if that is a C# variable within your cshtml page, that should be fine, as @templates.Count will be evaluated by the server and simply written into the resulting HTML page/JavaScript function, rather than passing it to the function - or worded differently: The server's output will change the body of your JavaScript function, rather than passing a value to a static function.

Comment: It is a C# variable (a string list), but I get a "Syntax error" error when trying to do this in javascript: if(@templates.Count > 0), but now it works..

Comment: Is that syntax error client side, or does your razor view crash? Using the @template.Count will only work if @template is actually declared and assigned in the cshtml.

If your view executes okay, but you get JavaScript errors, check out the JavaScript that's been onto the page. If you actually see `@template.Count` in the HTML page, it wasn't recognized as a variable on the server side. It *should* get evaluated there, and replaced by the actual value - so that you see something like `if (5 > 0)` in the fully rendered page.

Comment: It's okay, in the rendered page it evaluates. The syntax error shows in IDE, but at runtime it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden input field with the count:

```
@Html.Hidden("templatesCount", @templates.Count, new {@id="templatesCount"})
```

And read the value in **jQuery**:

```
$('#templatesCount').val();
```

In this way you can use the js as a separate file.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. I thisnk this is because I don't make a post and so the value of the hidden field doesn't seem to get set. I also can't actually use Chrome devTools to debug the javascript, since I'm using a partial view for this menu.